# Pygame. Нужно сделать анимацию

Tags: python, pygame

Всех приветствую! Начал изучать pygame и для моей игры понадобилось сделать прикрепленную камеру к персонажу, и я это сделал, но сейчас уже немного путаюсь в своем коде. В общем, нужно сделать к примеру idle анимацию для персонажа, я сделал пару попыток, но как - то не вышло.
Пожалуйста, подскажите как это выполнить. Заранее спасибо.
Вот мой код:

```
import sys
from random import randint


class Enemies(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, group):
        super(Enemies, self).__init__(group)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('enemy/name.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, group):
        super(Player, self).__init__(group)
        self.idle_animation = [pygame.image.load('player/idle/idle' + f"{i}.png") for i in range(1, 11)]
        self.idle = True
        self.image = pygame.image.load('player/idle/idle1.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.speed = 5

    def input(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_w]:
            self.direction.y = -1
            self.idle = False
        elif key[pygame.K_s]:
            self.direction.y = 1
            self.idle = False
        else:
            self.direction.y = 0
            self.idle = True

        if key[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1
            self.idle = False
        elif key[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
            self.idle = False
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
            self.idle = True

        if self.idle == True:
            for i in range(1, 11):
                self.image = pygame.image.load('player/idle/idle' + str(i) + '.png')

    def update(self):
        self.input()
        self.rect.center += self.direction * self.speed


class CameraGroup(pygame.sprite.Group):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CameraGroup, self).__init__()
        self.display_surface = pygame.display.get_surface()

        self.offset = pygame.math.Vector2()
        self.half_w = self.display_surface.get_size()[0] // 2
        self.half_h = self.display_surface.get_size()[1] // 2

        self.ground_surf = pygame.image.load('bg/bg.png')
        self.ground_rect = self.ground_surf.get_rect(topleft = (0,0))

    def center_target_camera(self, target):
        self.offset.x = target.rect.centerx - self.half_w
        self.offset.y = target.rect.centery - self.half_h

    def custom_draw(self, player):
        self.center_target_camera(player)

        ground_offset = self.ground_rect.topleft - self.offset
        self.display_surface.blit(self.ground_surf, ground_offset)

        for sprite in sorted(self.sprites(), key = lambda sprite: sprite.rect.centery):
            offset_pos = sprite.rect.topleft - self.offset
            self.display_surface.blit(sprite.image, offset_pos)


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

camera_group = CameraGroup()
player = Player((640, 360), camera_group)

for i in range(20):
    random_x = randint(0, 1000)
    random_y = randint(0, 1000)
    Enemies((random_x, random_y), camera_group)

fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
true = True

while true:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            event.type = pygame.QUIT

    screen.fill([255, 255, 255])

    camera_group.update()
    camera_group.custom_draw(player)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время апдейта ты просто 10 раз за кадр меняешь картинку. В смысле, ты делаешь это в коде, но показывается в итоге последняя. А тебе нужно раз в кадр менять картинку

Хороший пример есть [здесь в разделе Explosion](https://kidscancode.org/blog/2016/09/pygame_shmup_part_10/)
Немного изменила его под твои нужды

```
class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, center):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.anim = [...] # загрузка твоих картинок для анимации
        self.image = self.anim[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center

        self.frame = 0 # текущий кадр
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = 50 # как быстро кадры меняются

    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == len(self.anim):
                self.frame = 0
            
     
            self.image = self.anim[self.frame]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)